# Parse XML to JSON or JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I am receiving xml data from an api, check this link https://developers.cj.com/docs/rest-apis/advertiser-lookup

I need to parse xml to json or js object in order to use it properly.

I've tried xml2js, it converts stuff in the following way.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cj-api><error-message>  You must provide an Authorization header.</error-message></cj-api>
```

```json
{
  'cj-api': { 'error-message': [ 'You must provide an Authorization header.' ] }
}
```

In this case I dont need the array, just the simple value.
Is there a working parser that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `camaro` like this

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')

async function main() {
    const xml = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cj-api><error-message>  You must provide an Authorization header.</error-message></cj-api>

`

    const template = {
        errorMessage: '/cj-api/error-message'
    }
    const output = await transform(xml, template)
    console.log(output.message);
}

main()
```

output

```
  You must provide an Authorization header.
```